# How to get tabs in ICS and gingerbread to look the same?

Tags: java, android, tabs

Being new to android development, i have created a project using tabs using tutourials.

on Gingerbread it looks sort of like :

[image: Tab on Gingerbread]

While on ICS(emulator) it looks like:

[image: ICS]

Because of the sort of "Holo" type teme i have going i cant have the tab on the gingerbread style. I need help please it is killing me. Please dont tell me i have to figure out how to design it myself for Gingerbread i'll cry.

here is what i did:

```
      public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
      {

  private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabframelayout);


    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"),
            FragmentTab.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"),
            FragmentTab.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"),
            FragmentTab.class, null);


}
```

Comment: if youre goind to vote me down, at least say why

Answer (score 2):

It is greatly suggested that you use [Action Bar Tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) rather than using `TabHost`. While the Action Bar was added in Honeycomb, you can use compatibility libraries like [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) (which would give you consistent tabs across all devices and my personal recommendation) or follow the [Creating Backward-Compatible UIs training](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html) (which is very similar to what you are doing now).